# How can i get via AdSense Api the payment per Month and per Site

Tags: adsense-api

1) Hey i run API AdSense and im trying to get the total payment per month but filtered by site as well.
At the moment i can only extrect the amount of payment per month via https://www.googleapis.com/adsense/v1.4/accounts/accountId/payments but there is no way to filter there by Site
I can filter by site in this API https://www.googleapis.com/adsense/v1.4/accounts/accountId/reports but the payment that i get there are not accurate.

2) How can i get from the API the "InvalidTraffic" parameter per site ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

1) Reporting is the correct way to get this information. Common causes of metric discrepancies are using the wrong time zone and using the wrong currency type. Also, be aware that "earnings up to yesterday are accurate, [but] more recent earnings are estimated due to the possibility of spam, or exchange rate fluctuations."

2) Invalid Traffic isn't exposed in the API.

Comment: "Reporting " - where is it in the Api ?

Comment: Making a request to `GET https://www.googleapis.com/adsense/v1.4/accounts/accountId/reports` will generate a report. (https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/accounts/reports/generate)